# How to import certificates into a Java Keystore through group policy

Tags: java, dns, certificate, group-policy

Good morning, I'm a sysadmin that often has to hand jam a bunch of commands in command prompt to manually import a certain certificate into Java's cacerts keystore across dozens of workstations and repeat the process every time the computers are re-imaged.

I was wondering if there was anyway I could make or edit a group policy in a Windows10 Domain Controller that would automatically import the certificate into the keystore.

The commands I use to manually input the certificate are as follows:

```
"keytool -importcert -alias "alias" -file "C:\path\to\file.cer" -keystore "C:\path\to\keystore\cacerts" -storepass changeit"
```

Answer (score 0):

- In the tree pane *Group Policy Management Editor* window, expand *Computer Configuration*, *Policies* and click *Scripts*.
- In the content pane, double-click *Startup*.
- In the *Scripts* tab of the *Startup Properties* dialog, click *Show Files*.
- Copy the file you want to run to the opened location in *Windows Explorer*.
- Click *Add* on the *Scripts* tab.
- Click *Browse* in the *Add a Script* dialog and select the file using the file browser.
- Additionally in the *Add a Script* dialog, you can optionally specify parameters to configure how the script runs.
- Click *OK* to continue.